# ML.NET: how to retrain a text classification model with new data

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I am pretty new to machine learning in general, and to Microsoft ML.NET in particular.
What I am trying to do is to create a re-trainable model for text classification.
Suppose I have an Article (for training) and an ArticlePrediction (for the classification):

```
public class Article
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
}

public class ArticlePrediction
{
    public float[] Score { get; set; }
    public uint PredictedLabel { get; set; }
}
```

Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net) for re-trainable models and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3935), I concluded that I will need two pipelines - preparation pipeline and training pipeline. And a separate intermediate model for the "prepared" data, in order to do the re-training:

```
public class ArticlePrepared : Article
{
    [VectorType(???)]
    public float[] Features { get; set; }
    public uint Label { get; set; }
}
```

The actual training of the model is trivial:

```
public static void Train(MLContext ctx, IDataView data)
{
    var prepPipeline = ctx.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "Topic")
        .Append(ctx.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", "Text"));
    var trainPipeline = ctx.MulticlassClassification.Trainers
        .LbfgsMaximumEntropy("Label", "Features", historySize: 50, l1Regularization: 0.1f);

    var prepModel = prepPipeline.Fit(data);
    var prepData = prepModel.Transform(data);
    var trainModel = trainPipeline.Fit(prepData);

    ctx.Model.Save(prepModel, data.Schema, PreparationPipelinePath);
    ctx.Model.Save(trainModel, prepData.Schema, TrainingPipelinePath);
}
```

The retraining part is the one I am struggling with and I now have my doubts if this is even possible:

```
public static void Retrain(MLContext ctx, Article article)
{
    var prepModel = ctx.Model.Load(PreparationPipelinePath, out var _);
    var retrainModel = ctx.Model.Load(TrainingPipelinePath, out var _) as ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>;
    var modelParams = (MaximumEntropyModelParameters)retrainModel.Model;

    var prepData = prepModel.Transform(ctx.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new[] { article }));

    var retrainedModel = ctx.MulticlassClassification.Trainers
        .LbfgsMaximumEntropy("Label", "Features", historySize: 50, l1Regularization: 0.1f)
        .Fit(prepData, modelParams); // boom!

    ctx.Model.Save(retrainedModel, prepData.Schema, TrainingPipelinePath);
}
```

The exception that is received is **No valid training instances found, all instances have missing features.**
A couple of questions I have:

- It seems to me like each word in the text is being converted to a model feature. This means that when I try to retrain the model with a new `Article` the trained model does not have all the features of this new `Article` (because the new text, that I would like to retrain the model with, is different). Is this the reason for the exception I receive?
- When it comes to featurizing text, it is impossible to tell how many features the prepared `ArticlePrepared` model should have (i.e. the size of the `VectorType` attribute, or the length of the `Features` array property). Is it possible to work with dynamic number of features? If you inspect the GitHub repo (link below), you'll see that the `VectorType` has size of 131, but this is a hardcoded value that was taken from the already saved schema. Needless to say, hardcoding like this is not going to work in a real-world scenario.

I have create a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ripebananas/mlnet-retrain-text-classificator-issues) that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do or am I going in a totally wrong direction? Any help or insights are appreciated.